# If my button has an active class do something else, otherwise jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is my toggle button,i want if button has .active class do something else do otherwise.

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-toggle" data-toggle="button" ></button>
```

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Comment: if($('button').hasClass('active')){ is active }else{ is not active}

Answer (score 0):

**Happy Coding :)**

```js
$('.btn-toggle').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('btn-active')){
    alert('button has activat class so perform task 1');
    // write your task 1
    // ...
    } else {
    alert('button has not activat class so perform task 2');
    // write your task 2
    // ...
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-active');
});
```

```css
.btn-toggle {
background-color : red;
}

.btn-active {
background-color : blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-toggle">Button</button>
```

Comment: if you find this usefull please upvote it. thank you :) @david